# How to execute my superb.activity(); prototype function in 'console.log' with other strings ? is that possible?

Tags: javascript

```
    var date = new Date();
var establishCalc = date.getFullYear();

var Textile = function(firm, job, establish, adress ){
    this.firm = firm;
    this.job = job;
    this.establish = establish;
    this.adress = adress;

}

Textile.prototype.activity = function(){
 console.log( establishCalc - this.establish);    
}

Textile.prototype.intro = function(){
    console.log( this.firm + ' yaptiği ' + this.job + ' işeriyle kurulduğu ' + this.establish +
                ' senesinden beri tam ' + this.activity + ' yıldır ' + this.adress + ' bolgemizde hizmet vermektedir.');

}

var superb = new Textile ('Süper Tesktil', 'perde', 1980, 'Tekirdağ');

superb.activity();
superb.intro(); // Output is like that 




/*Süper Tesktil yaptiği perde işeriyle kurulduğu 1980 senesinden beri tam function(){
 console.log( establishCalc - this.establish);    
} yıldır Tekirdağ bolgemizde hizmet vermektedir. */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First return some value from `Textile.prototype.activity`

```
Textile.prototype.activity = function(){
  return establishCalc - this.establish;    
}
```

then change `this.activity` to `this.activity()` in `Textile.prototype.intro` method

```
Textile.prototype.intro = function(){
console.log( this.firm + ' yaptiği ' + this.job + ' işeriyle kurulduğu ' + this.establish +
            ' senesinden beri tam ' + this.activity() + ' yıldır ' + this.adress + ' bolgemizde hizmet vermektedir.');}
```